# How to view a saved Orbeon form without triggering recalculations?

Tags: orbeon, xforms

The form should be read-only and load it's data from already saved formdata, without defined recalculations.

The View Mode of Form Runner, doesn't prevent recalculations, but just make all fields read-only.I have searched in Orbeon Form Documentation, but haven't found anything else.

Is there any way to accomplish this behaviour using some built-in config property, or should i change EVERY existing defined calculations?

Comment: Calculations are expected to be "live", as they would in a spreadsheet. So, the form should behave as if they were always instantly recalculated. (Of course, behind the scene, you would like a minimum number of recalculations to happen, for performance reasons, but this is an implementation detail.) What is the use case where you would *not* recalculations to be "live"?

Comment: a saves version of this form, should show its save values, because there is the possibility that some constants imported to the model have been updated, and so i want to keep the old values in the previous saved form.

Comment: That's not unreasonable and I think that would be something to think about, but currently calculations are not disabled in view mode.

Comment: I can see how this would sense, maybe even in most cases, when going from *edit* to *view*. Maybe a "print  preview" in Excel would be a good analogy: you wouldn't expect any recalculation to happen between the time you ask for a print preview, and the time that view is generated. However, @oikonomopo, are you saying that you also expect this to work with save? I.e. no recalculations being done between the time the form is saved, and re-opened?

Comment: A "print preview" in Excel would be a good analogy! Exactly, not with save!